# OceanWP change text color menu based on current anchored section

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using **OceanWP theme** and **Elementor plugin** as my page builder. I've created my anchor ID in elementor then link it to it's menu. The problem is that current menu didn't highlight everytime I scroll on corresponding anchored ID. How to highlight menu based on current anchored section? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can highlight menu using with custom CSS that you can add to your theme to change font color of navigation menus.

E.g.

```html
#top-menu  li.menu-item a {
color:#ff0000;
}
```

Custom Code of CSS for your theme,

```html
.current_page_item,
.current-menu-ancestor {
 background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Hope!! It's works !

Comment: This code is only for current active page. It only change the color of my current "PAGE" not per section everytime I scroll "anchor ID".